# how to add a value to a parameter without quotes

Tags: sass

I'm using SASS to generate some styles, but I can't figure this one out.

Example:`$v: round(($s / 12) * 100) + "%";`

results in: `width: "25%";`

but I want it to result in `width: 25%;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding quotes to a number turns it into a string.

Try this instead:

```
$v: round(($s / 12) * 100%);
```

Event better:

```
$v: round(percentage($s / 12));
```